# MySQL group by query complexity analysis

Tags: mysql, complexity-theory

Which is the complexity of the "group by" statement in MySQL?

I am managing vaery big tables and I also would like to know if there is any method to calculate how much time a query is going to take.

Comment: SQL is designed such that your dbms can optimize as much as possible. Anyway, just doing some profiling would be your best bet in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossible to answer with knowledge of what the entire query looks like. Some group bys can be prohibitively expensive while others are very cheap, it all depends on how the indexes in the database are set up, if the value you group by can be cached etc.

For example, this is a very cheap group by:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT, KEY(a));
SELECT * FROM WHERE 1 GROUP BY a;
```

Since a is an index.

But for something like this, it's very expensive since it would require a table scan.

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT);
SELECT * FROM WHERE 1 GROUP BY a;
```

Generally if a key is not available, the database will creates a temporary table in memory for group by clauses, go through all the values, insert each value into the temporary table with an index to the corresponding row in the result set, then it will select from the temporary table, pick the first row from each column and send that back as the result. Depending on if you use the "extra" rows per group by clause (ie. using MAX(), GROUP_CONCAT() or similar) it will need to fetch all rows again.

You can use EXPLAIN to figure out what strategy MySQL will use, the 'Extra' (in ascending order of cost to execute) 'Using index' if an index can be used, 'Using filesort' if reading all rows from disk will be necessary, and column will contain 'Using Temporary' if a temporary will be required